# Div not displaying properly in early IE versions

Tags: internet-explorer, html

http://www.signport.co.uk/test/asg_automotive.html

This page displays correctly in Chrome, Firefox, IE 8 and IE9, however in IE6 and IE7 #mainmenu3 div doesn't overlay over the photograph, instead it pushes it down.

Does anyone have an idea how to fix this?

Thanks

Comment: The best solution to all this issues is to not use IE...

Answer (score 0):

Check your HTML in http://validator.w3.org/ you will probably find something that you forgot to close.

If you are using some CSS, please note that not all CSS codes are supported in old versions of browsers. so be very careful and check every element until you find what you have missed.

Comment: I am also not sure if HTML5 doctype will work on old versions of IE. so, try to change it to another doctype and see if it will work.